# One to many config in Entity Framework and Join Expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF codefirst .I am confused on relationship in Entities .I have Two entities `Student` and `Standard` . Shown below

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StdandardId { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

They have One to Many relationship.
I can do this by simple join expression like this

```
var list = StudentList.Join
          (StandardList,c => c.StdandardId,o => o.StandardId,(c, o) => new
          {
              StudentId = c.StudentId,
              StudentName = c.StudentName,
              StandardName = o.StandardName
          });
```

Then why should i configure forienkey One-to-Many relationship  like

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StdandardId { get; set; }    
    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any key benifits.?  Which one will perform well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can result in answers ranging to the size of essays.

I'll try to keep it essential. In short, Foreign Keys are used to ensure referential integrity.

In your select statement it might not make a difference, but think about update, insert and delete statements, and hurdles you'd have to take in order to cascade everything down to the last table.

Lets assume your Foreign Key constraint is set to `Cascade`. Whenever you make a change in your mastertable, the change is cascaded down to every child table. You'd have to manually join every table in your statement to implement the same.

If the constraint is set to `Restrict` you can not delete a `Student` as long as there are still `Standards` referencing to it. Again, You'd have to check this by hand in your statements every time.

You may very well be able to do this in your head, but you will make an error, and then you may be stuck with inconsistent data, when money is on the line.

---

And then there is comfort in EF.

I could join my data, but if there are Foreign Keys and tehrefore relationships in place I could write

```
var students = context.Students.Include(o => o.Enrollments);
```

and use it in my View with

```
@foreach(var enrollment in Model.Enrollments)
{
   //...
}
```

In essence, this is not a problem related purely to Entity Framework, but to relational databases.

Have a look at [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and [Foreign Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the OP is wondering about the use of foreign keys in the database. I think the question is, *given* foreign keys, do I reflect them in my class model?

Comment: I thought about that as well. In the end it is not very clear from his  wording, but with our 2 answers he'll be covered I guess.

Comment: What a luxury :) The second part of you answer addresses the OP's question anyway.

Comment: I think the key part one could argue is *They have One to Many relationship. I can do this by simple join expression like this*, which could mean "logically they have this relationship" or it could be rephrased as "I have implemented this relationship already". Hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

The navigation property (`Students`) is an implicit join. but it's an *outer join*. If you join explicitly you can enforce an *inner join*, which will generally perform better. So do this if performance is critical.

So give yourself the opportunity to do both. Create navigation properties and join explicitly when necessary.

The benefit of navigation properties is a much more succinct syntax. e.g.

```
from standard in Standards
select new { standard.StandardName , NrOfStudents = standard.Students.Count() })
```

For this query you always want an outer join, because you'd also want to report the standards with zero students.

Or an implicit `SelectMany`:

```
from standard in Standards
where standard.StandardId == id
from student in standard.Students
select new { student. ... }
```

Navigation properties help you to carry out joins without this verbose join syntax.